# is new version of node-redis able to interact the old redis-servers

Tags: node.js, redis, node-redis

i was using node-redis version 3.1.2  and updated to 4.0.3 . my redis-server version is more than two years old . will i able to interact with the old redis-server with new node-redis client . am current facing some issues with this

- timeout issue
- connection closed issues

i have followed the migration guide and couldn't solve the issues .

```
var client = redis.createClient({
    host: host,
    port: port,
    auth_pass: password,
    tls: { 
         checkServerIdentity: () => undefined 
    }
});
await client.connect();
```